# lsnrctl gices no errors nor any output though lsnr.ora file is correct

Tags: linux, oracle11g, listener, oracle-sqldeveloper, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Oracle in my Ubuntu machine and though it got installed I cannot access the database. Though I have created the listener by running ./netca I cannot see any output when I run lsnrctl command. When I run ./netca, I can still see the previously created listeners. lsnrctl gives no ouput. Which means no errors nor any output. Please advice.

Comment: How do you issue `lsnrctl`? I.e. to check listener status you need to pass a subcommand: `lsnrctl status`

Comment: @myaut when you type lsnrctl there should be some output showing the version and everything of the listener utility right? that I dont get in my ubuntu. I have tried in some friends' machines they do get the output. Even when I type lsnrctl status, I get no output. Please help

Comment: Can you upload the output of `which lsnrctl`?